# How to read analog pin data from the Blynk HTTP RESTful API?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, blynk

I am making my own app for my project with Blynk so I need the Blynk API it works fine with Digital Pins I am getting the right value. But I tried with analog pin I used this syntax: http://blynk-cloud.com/auth_token/get/pin

When I give the analog pin it shows the value as 0 always but in Blynk app it shows correctly.

```
["0"]
```

This is what I get when I give

```
http://188.166.206.43/6OlIG-nyToVY*******************/get/A0
```

How can I get the analog pin value?

Comment: [Try `D17` instead of `A0`](https://community.blynk.cc/t/http-api-restful/8844/23)

Comment: Thank you!! It works!!

Comment: If you don't mind Can you posted it as an answer to mark it is Solved!!

Comment: It's ok, I don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type D17 instead of A0. It Works!!